# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/libodep/lib/libintl.8.dylib

Tags: python, macos, libreoffice

I want to use unoconv with LibreOffice 4.2, but it seems like I can not start the python of LibreOffice.

When I run

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/LibreOfficePython.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/LibreOfficePython  -v
```

The error is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/libodep/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/LibreOfficePython.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/LibreOfficePython
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue.  The fix is ugly, but essentially follows Michael's approach.  The lib is provided by MacPorts and installed there:

```
> find /opt/ -name 'libintl*'
/opt/local/include/libintl.h
/opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
...
```

A simple softlink into `/usr/` does the trick, but gee do I dislike polluting trees like this!

```
> sudo bash
> mkdir -p /usr/local/libodep/lib
> ln -s /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib /usr/local/libodep/lib/libintl.8.dylib
```

With this, the Python 3.3 from LibreOffice runs.  I sure hope that somebody at LibreOffice is going to fix this.  Anybody know if a bug has been filed?

Comment: This *might* also work instead of setting the softlink: `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib` (I haven't tried this).

Answer (score 19):

Not directly an answer to the original question, but I ended up on this page after searching for the same error message, while running `gpg`. Turns out gettext was mangled during upgrade of ios. The following sorted it:

```
brew install gettext
brew link gettext --force
```

Comment: This worked for me! But I also had to nuke (`rm -rf`) the previous version of gettext

Comment: I landed here from searching fro another issue and this solution worked for me as well. Thnks!

Comment: worked for me after some brew meltdown on the mac and various reinstalls. yey, amazing!

Comment: This perfectly resolves my issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The library it's attempting to load isn't a standard dylib on MacOS.  Whoever created LibreOffice should have either included the dylib in their app package somewhere or they should have included instructions on how to set things up properly for LibreOffice.

From what I can tell, it looks like you need to [install MacPorts](http://mysolr.com/tips/setting-up-macports-on-lion/) in order to pick up libintl.8.dylib.

And MacPorts is likely to install that library into "`/opt/local/lib/`" instead of "`/usr/local/libodep/`".  Not sure if LibreOffice is smart enough to know what to do in that case but you can do a symbolic link from a file in one directory to a sym link in another directory in a pinch if you're desperate.

Comment: Hi , I remove ports in order to use homebrew

Comment: then you need to figure out a way to get that library back, or re-build & reinstall it outside of MacPorts.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue as:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from:
/opt/local/bin/yasm
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I had to install `MacPorts` and `gettext`, which installs the `libintl.*` libraries in `/opt/local/lib`
`MacPorts` defines the dependency of `yasm` on `gettext`

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the same topic here for followup:
https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/125

Though the provided answers didn't work for me, installing macports didn't work for me,
libintl.8.dylib I didn't find on /opt/local/lib/

I found others have the problem not being compatible. 
gettext also didn't work for me.